# ReactJS fetch full CSV

Tags: reactjs, fetch, papaparse, react-highcharts

I'm trying to fetch and parse a CSV file in a ReactJS project of mine. I'm reading from the stream chunk by chunk and then parsing it into [Date,data] value pairs. The intention is to then use the values array to load up a Highcharts/Highstock graph.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HighStock from "highcharts/highstock";

import Papa from 'papaparse';

async function readAndParseData() {
  const response = await fetch(dataURI)
  const reader = response.body.getReader()
  const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8')

  let values = []

  //Keep reading in chunks until finished
  let value, done;
  while (!done) {
    ({ value, done } = await reader.read());
    if (done) {
      break
    }

    const csv = decoder.decode(value) // the csv text
    const results = await Papa.parse(csv, { header: false }) // object with { data, errors, meta }
    const rows = results.data // array of objects

    //Put data into [[x1,y2], [x2,y2], ...] format
    rows.slice(1).forEach(ele => {
      values.push([Date.parse(ele[0]), parseFloat(ele[2])])
    });
    return values
  }
}


useEffect(() => {

  //Gets and sets graph data
  async function getGraphData() {
    let graphData = await readAndParseData()
    console.log(graphData)
    setDataSource(graphData)
  }
  getGraphData()

}, []);
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not always getting the full CSV data, rather sometimes it's just the first chunk or a few chunks. I've tried asyncs and awaits so that it returns only once the whole stream is finished and all data is in the values array. What am I missing here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that's stuck on this, here's what I did:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HighStock from "highcharts/highstock";

import Papa from 'papaparse';

async function readAndParseData() {
    const response = await fetch(dataURI)
    const reader = response.body.getReader()
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8')

    //Keep reading in chunks until finished
    let csvText = ""
    let value, done;
    while (!done) {
      ({ value, done } = await reader.read());
      if (done) {
        break
      }

      const csv = decoder.decode(value) // the csv text
      csvText = csvText.concat(csv) //concat new csv chunk
    }

    const results = await Papa.parse(csvText, { header: false }) // object with { data, errors, meta }
    const rows = results.data // array of objects

    //Put data into [[x1,y2], [x2,y2], ...] format
    let values = []
    rows.slice(1).forEach(ele => {
      values.push([Date.parse(ele[0]), parseFloat(ele[2])])
    });

    return values
  }


  useEffect(() => {

    //Gets and sets graph data
    async function getGraphData() {
      let graphData = await readAndParseData()
      setDataSource(graphData)
    }
    getGraphData()

  }, []);
```

Just keep on reading in all the data and decoding it into a single string chunk after chunk. Then after all the data is read, transform and set it.